# Scrollbar Customizations That Are Supported by the W3C

Tags: html, css, w3c

I hope this question is on-topic for StackOverflow. I have seen many comments here that a lot of web developers scrollbar customizations are non-standard and not yet approved by the powers that be (W3C.org). My philosophy is to design to the standards Issued for Use by the Industry Organization that guides web standards and specifications because a properly, dependable, working website is what my users want.

Approved scrollbar customization standards that the W3C.org has approved. Where can I get that standard?

If I am off subject again, could you possibly get me some answers first, then pass me to the Red Queen for off with the head?

Thanks Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "standard" [Scrollbars CSS Module - Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/) is in its early stages of adoption and that would be the only one matching your requirements.

Until it's implemented, you're limited to non-standard [CSS scrollbar styling support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar).

Another option (the only production ready one, really) is to use a plugin which basically replaces the scrollbar mechanism with custom HTML elements.
Most of them have trouble with at least one mobile device type (either on IoS or on Android) and the sane solution is to detect it and simply disable the plugin for that case.

**Note 1**: while W3C support is a very wise thing to look for when choosing how to build your page, it doesn't mean much without browser support. In theory, if Chrome refuses to implement something today, considering their market share is above 60%, they simply won't and nobody can do anything about it. But your clients will require their page to work in Chrome.

However, much of Chrome's popularity comes from strictly sticking to web standards so far, so it would be safe to assume they will continue to abide by them.

**Note 2**: I recommend [this article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/scroll-to-the-future-modern-javascript-css-scrolling-implementations). It's well written, quite informative and up to date on the current state of scrollbar customizations.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks.

Comment: For some time I have looked at other websites. Corporate websites, be they fashion, entertainment, technology, merchandising, etc... all use the standard scrollbar. The "Scroll To the Future" link makes the case (for my purposes, at least) to stay with simplicity until W3C issues the standard and Chrome, Safari, and Firefox support that standard. Question asked, question answered.